# How to hide a bootstrap-vue modal after clicking a button in laravel vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am new to laravel and vue.js.

In a blade view, I have a bootstrap-vue modal which includes a vue.js component for a full-text search and sends a post request to the backend when clicking a button.

So I want to hide this modal after clicking the same button after performing the request.

I have tried to access modal using ref attribute and then call the hide() method as stated in the documentation [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/#using-show-and-hide-component-methods), but it doesn't work, I don't know what I am missing.

Here is my code:

**index.blade.php**:

```
@extends('layouts.app', ['navId' => 'teams'])
@section('title', 'Teams')
@section('content')
    <div class="container-fluid mt-5 pt-5 col-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 offset-6">
                <b-button v-b-modal="'myModal'">Add Users</b-button>
                <!-- The modal -->
                <b-modal id="myModal" class="" size="s" centered :hide-footer="true" :hide-header="true">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <h4 class="">Add new Participant</h4>
                    </div>
                    <user-search />
                </b-modal>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

**UserSearch.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div class="" ref="myModalRef">
        <div class="card">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search ..." v-model="keywords" v-on:keyup="autoComplete" 
                    class="form-control bg-light border-0">
            <div class="panel-footer mt-2" v-if="results.length">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <div class="result-item my-3">
                        <li class="media mx-2 my-3" v-for="result in results" :key="result.id" @mouseover="hover = true"
                                                        @mouseleave="hover = false"
                                                        :class="{ active: hover }">
                            <img :src="result.avatar_path ? result.avatar_path : '/img/dashboard/user-placeholder.png'" 
                                    class="rounded-circle align-self-center mr-3" width="40" height="40"/>
                            <h5 v-text="result.name" class="mt-3"></h5>
                            <div class="media-body d-flex justify-content-end mt-3">
                                <b-form-checkbox :id="'selected-user' + result.id" v-model="usersToAdd" :value="result" class="" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div v-if="usersToAdd.length" class="col-3 my-5 mx-auto">
            <b-button type="submit" @click="sendInviteToUsers">Done</b-button>
        </div>

    </div>

</template>
<script>
import bForm from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/form/form';
import bFormGroup from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/form-group/form-group';
import bFormInput from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/form-input/form-input';

export default {
    name: 'UserSearch',
    data() {
        return {
            keywords: '',
            results: [],
            hover: false,
            usersToAdd: [],
        };
    },

    methods: {
        autoComplete() {
            this.results = [];
            if(this.keywords.length > 2 ){
                this.$axios.get('/api/users/search', { params: { keywords: this.keywords } })
                .then(response => {
                    this.results = response.data;
                })
                .catch(() => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.showErrorToast('An error occurred while Fetching Users. Please try again later');
                });

                // .catch(error => {});
            }

        },

        sendInviteToUsers() {
            if(this.usersToAdd.length) {
                this.$axios.post('/api/teams/invite-with-email/', this.usersToAdd);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is bootstrap-vue was not able to find the modal reference correctly.Try something like this,

Remove **modal** from your **index.blade.php** and include it in **UserSearch.vue** with the **ref** attribute

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app', ['navId' => 'teams'])
@section('title', 'Teams')
@section('content')
    <div class="container-fluid mt-5 pt-5 col-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 offset-6">
                <b-button v-b-modal="'myModal'">Add Users</b-button>

                <!--Removed modal tag from here and included it in UserSearch.vue-->
                <user-search />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

**UserSearch.vue**

```
<template>
    <!--Add b-modal tag and ref attribute here-->
    <b-modal id="myModal" class="" size="s" centered :hide-footer="true" :hide-header="true" ref="myModalRef">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <h4 class="">Add new Participant</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search ..." v-model="keywords" v-on:keyup="autoComplete"
               class="form-control bg-light border-0">
        <div class="panel-footer mt-2" v-if="results.length">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <div class="result-item my-3">
                    <li class="media mx-2 my-3" v-for="result in results" :key="result.id" @mouseover="hover = true"
                        @mouseleave="hover = false"
                        :class="{ active: hover }">
                        <img :src="result.avatar_path ? result.avatar_path : '/img/dashboard/user-placeholder.png'"
                             class="rounded-circle align-self-center mr-3" width="40" height="40"/>
                        <h5 v-text="result.name" class="mt-3"></h5>
                        <div class="media-body d-flex justify-content-end mt-3">
                            <b-form-checkbox :id="'selected-user' + result.id" v-model="usersToAdd" :value="result" class="" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3 my-5 mx-auto">
        <b-button type="submit" @click="sendInviteToUsers">Done</b-button>
    </div>

</b-modal>

</template>
<script>
import bForm from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/form/form';
import bFormGroup from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/form-group/form-group';
import bFormInput from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/form-input/form-input';

export default {
    name: 'UserSearch',
    data() {
        return {
            keywords: '',
            results: [],
            hover: false,
            usersToAdd: [],
        };
    },

    methods: {
        autoComplete() {
            this.results = [];
            if(this.keywords.length > 2 ){
                this.$axios.get('/api/users/search', { params: { keywords: this.keywords } })
                .then(response => {
                    this.results = response.data;
                })
                .catch(() => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.showErrorToast('An error occurred while Fetching Users. Please try again later');
                });

                // .catch(error => {});
            }

        },

        sendInviteToUsers() {
            if(this.usersToAdd.length) {
                this.$axios.post('/api/teams/invite-with-email/', this.usersToAdd).then(response => {
                    //Do something you want
                    this.$refs.myModalRef.hide();
                }).catch(error => {
                    //Handle the errors
                    this.$refs.myModalRef.hide();
                })
            }

        }
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Inside your "sendInviteToUsers" function edit the function as above. In here the modal will close after you receive the api response from the server.